# É possível passar parametros de uma aplicação pra outra via Query String? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-6

Eu tenho 2 aplicações Angulas, Aplicação 1 e aplicação 2. Eu preciso passar via query string o token da aplicação 1 para aplicação 2. Alguém tem um exemplo? Estou perdido e não encontrei nada parecido na internet. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, o ideal seria você ter um intermediador entre os dois, o famoso backend.. onde poderia ser feito de varias maneias, você poderia gerar um simples token com isso, instale o [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)

```
import { random, times } from 'lodash';
    export function getRandomUID() {
      return times(20, () => random(35).toString(36)).join('');
    }
```

um jeito sem backend, seria você salvar no [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) e pegar isso atraves do cookie também, use os exemplos no npm acima